# Jquery Validation Works with Default [Required] but not with custom class

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

Based on the following link: [Multi Language - Data Annotations](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/130586/Simplified-localization-for-DataAnnotations)
Make a series of classes to translate the texts of the Data Annotation.
Everything works fine on the server side, but client side validation does not work.

If i use: `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
public string Name { get; set; }`

Validation on the client side works correctly, but if I use:

`[Infrastructure.Required]//My custom class
public string Name { get; set; }`

It works only on the server side.

This is the class that I am currently using:

```
namespace project.Infrastructure
{
public class RequiredAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute
{
    private string _displayName;
    public RequiredAttribute()
    {
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_Required";
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        _displayName = validationContext.DisplayName;
        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        var msg = WebsiteTranslations.GetTranslationErrorMessage(Settings.LanguageId, "Required", WebsiteTranslations.GetTranslation(name, 1, Settings.LanguageId));
        return string.Format(msg, _displayName);
    }
    public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetClientValidationRules(System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        return new[] { new ModelClientValidationRequiredRule((ErrorMessage)) };
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer from this post: [validation-type-names-in-unobtrusive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059904/validation-type-names-in-unobtrusive-client-validation-rules-must-be-unique-the)
The GetClientValidationRules Method is like this:

```
    public IEnumerable GetClientValidationRules(System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var clientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(ErrorMessage),
            ValidationType = "required"
        };
        yield return new[] { clientValidationRule };
    }
```

And in the Application_Start inside Global.asax:

```
      DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredAttribute), typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter));
        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(StringLengthAttribute), typeof(StringLengthAttributeAdapter));
```